# Customizing Ubuntu Server Startup Message

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server

I have an Ubuntu server (15.04) that I am using for testing in a group. Is there a way I can customize the startup message (probably not the correct terminology) to include the IP address.

[image: Startup Message]

So rather than "Ubuntu 10.04 presta tty" it would say "Ubuntu 10.04 presta tty 192.168.1.99" or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The banner above console login prompts is stored in **`/etc/issue`**. Depending on system, various expansions can be used in it, such as `\4` for the IPv4 address (see `man agetty`).